# Creating CLIPS Native Library on a Windows Docker Container

Tags: clips

I'm trying to create the CLIPS native library as a title.
I've follow this guide, but unfortunately in my Docker container i have installed an Alpine Linux distro.

> 10.6.3 Creating the Native Library On Linux Launch the Terminal application (as described in section 10.2). Set the directory to the CLIPSJNI/lbrary-src directory (using the cd command).
>
> To create a native library, enter the following command (where  is either ubuntu, fedora, debian, mint, or centos):
>
> make -f makefile.lnx
>
> Once you have create the shared library, copy the libCLIPSJNI.so file from the CLIPSJNI/library-src to the top-level CLIPSJNI directory.

I need therefore to create libCLIPSJNI.so but my distro (alpine) is not specified in the set of values about  values.

How can i do?

P.S. Gary, I need you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look inside the makefile you'll see that the only difference between the various distributions is the value assigned to the variable JAVA_HOME. For ubuntu, debian, and mint it's set to /usr/lib/jvm/default-java. For fedora and centos it's set to /usr/lib/jvm/java. So determine where java is installed for the alpine distribution and if it's the same as one of the existing distributions in the makefile, compile using that distribution. Alternately create a new build target for alpine in the makefile and set JAVA_HOME to the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Always the best.